# Prove if $0<a<1$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{n}=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good morning i have a proof of this exercise but i don't know if my proof is correct. please review that!

---

Problem:

Prove if $0<a<1$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{n}=0  $

---

Proof:

Let $0<a<1$ then

$$a^{n}=e^{\ln(a)^{n}}=e^{n\ln(a)}>n\ln(a)$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\ln(a)=\ln(a)\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n=-\infty$$

And then:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{n\ln(a)}=e^{-\infty}=0.$$

---

Now, it's correct my proof? Thanks.

Comment: Why, or what for,  did you write $\;e^{n\log n}\ge n\log n\;$ , a rather trivial inequality as the left side is always positive whereas the right side is negative since $\;0<a<1\;$ ? (I'm guessing you meant $\;a>0\;$ .

Comment: What if $a=-1?$

Comment: Sorry $0<a<1$ i don'twrite that! @zhw.

Comment: Other than the odd inequality mentioned above and writing $\;e^{-\infty}\;$ , which can look non-formally correct, I think your proof is basically correct. I'd rather write, mentioning the continuity of exponential function: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{n\log a}=e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\log a}=0$$

Comment: You've inexplicably included the inequality $e^{n\ln(a)}>n\ln(a).$ Why?

Answer (score 2):

Fix $a \in (0,1)$ and define $b=1/a>1$. Then
$$
a^n=e^{n \ln a}=e^{n \ln b^{-1}}=e^{-n \ln b}.
$$
Now
$$
b>1 \implies \lim_{n\to \infty}{n \ln b} = \infty.
$$
Therefore, since $\mathrm{exp}$ is a continuous function, we conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} a^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n \ln b}=e^{-\lim_{n\to \infty}n \ln b}=0.
$$

Comment: Why go to this $b>1$ business? Just use $a^n = e^{n\ln a}$ and then $n\ln a \to -\infty.$

Comment: I know it is unuseful, it just seems to be more intuitive

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $a^n$ is positive, decreasing and bounded below by $0.$ Therefore it converges to some $L \in [0,1).$ It follows that $a\cdot a^n \to a\cdot L.$ But $a\cdot a^n = a^{n+1},$ so it also converges to $L.$ Therefore $aL = L.$ If $L>0,$ we get $a=1,$ contradiction. Therefore $a^n\to 0.$

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a^k$ is a geometric series that converges for $a \in (0, 1)$.  The convergence of this series implies $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^n = 0$.

Comment: Right. This is a strange problem. This is a result that is so basic that I wonder if the proofs involving $e^{a\ln n}$ and the like might be circular.

Comment: @zhw., now that I think about it, I don't know how to prove that the geometric series converges without using the very fact we're trying to prove.  :/

Comment: Good point.$\,\,$

Answer (score 0):

let $\varepsilon >0,0<\left| a \right| <1$ using Bernoulli inequation we have $$\\ \frac { 1 }{ { \left| a \right|  }^{ n } } ={ \left( 1+\left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left| a \right|  }^{ n } } -1 \right)  \right)  }^{ n }>1+n\left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left| a \right|  } } -1 \right) >n\left( \frac { 1 }{ { \left| a \right|  } } -1 \right) \\ { \left| a \right|  }^{ n }=\left| { a }^{ n } \right| <\frac { \left| a \right|  }{ n\left( 1-\left| a \right|  \right)  } <\varepsilon ,\forall n>\frac { \left| a \right|  }{ \varepsilon \left( 1-\left| a \right|  \right)  } $$

Comment: But my proof are wrong?