# Prove if $a \in \mathbb{R}, |a| <1$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^n =0$. How to prove the case when $1<a<0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm reading Introduction to Analysis by Maxwell Rosenlicht. On page 50, he proved it in this way: [image]

[image]

My question is why did he omit $a<0$?

I am trying to prove it in this way:

$a^{n+1} - a^n = a^n(a-1)$.

If $a=0$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^n = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 0^n = 0$.

If $a > 0$, we can prove it as how Rosenlicht did.

But, what if $a<0$? Don't we need to prove that separately? $a^n$ is jumping around $0$, but it is getting closer and closer to $0$

Comment: $c_n\to 0$ iff $|c_n|\to0$

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown what if we have another statement that ask to prove something like $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a^n = a$ where $a$ may not be $0$. Is it still true that $a_n \rightarrow a$ iff $| a_n | \rightarrow a$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove if $0&lt;a&lt;1$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{n}=0 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854271/prove-if-0a1-then-lim-n-rightarrow-inftyan-0)

Comment: @Maneesh Narayanan Sorry, my question is different from that. I am asking why Rosenlicht can combine 3 cases into 1.

Answer (score 1):

No, we don't have to deal with the case $-1<a<0$ separately. Rosenlicht dealt with that case in the first sentence: “First note that $|a^n|=|a|^n$, so that we may suppose that $a\geqslant0$.”

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $-1<a<0$. Then $|a^{n}-0|=|a^{n}|=|a|^{n}$ but $0<|a|<1$, so $\lim |a|^{n}=0$, which proves the result.